# how to list the project collections on TFS?

Tags: collections, tfs, project

i wang to get the all project collections on tfs, there are many samples that can do it through TFS jdk. but i want to use command line tool to do. Is there a way to list all the project collections via the command line? if so, what command line can use? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Still want this in 2019!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy to do this through tf.exe.

However you can call the API directly from powershell or (one would assume) shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query on Tfs_configuration database:

```
SELECT * from DatabaseId
```

You will get the details for collections.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Try using TFS tf command-line tool as follows:

```
tf dir /server:https://yourTFSServerURL
```

If you want to list all projects in a collection you can do it as follows:

```
tf dir /server:https://yourTFSServerURL/yourCollectionName
```